# How to import requests_toolbelt correctly in google app engine?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, python-requests

I am trying to import requests_toolbelt package in google app engine but keep getting import error. Already checked at https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adapters.html#appengineadapte and https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests also gives same error.

It works fine on local but after deploying, the error appears: 
    ImportError: No module named requests_toolbelt.adapters

I have this:

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine

if not os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):
    appengine.monkeypatch()
```

requirements.txt has

```
requests
requests_toolbelt
```

Comment: can yo show the full traceback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Python2.7 in the Standard environment, having the `requests_toolbelt` library in the `requirements.txt` file is not enough to upload it to App Engine, since it is not one of the [Built-in Third-party Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27).

To add it, you can follow this steps, as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27):

- Run the following command:

  `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt`

  This will install all the packages to the local environment, and copy them to the `lib` folder afterwards. [Documentation on this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-t).
- Create the following file, named `appengine_config.py`:

  ```
  from google.appengine.ext import vendor
  # Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
  vendor.add('lib')
  ```

  Note that this file needs to be in the same root path as the `app.yaml`, and the `'lib'` string repersents the path from this root to the folder you created in the previous point.
- Redeploy the application with `gcloud app deploy`

Once that is done, you should be able to run the application without errors related to the library.

As a side note, these steps are only a requirement in Python 2.7 in the Standard App Engine environment. In Python3 or in Flexible, having the libraries listed in the `requirements.txt` file is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I was recommend also to add the "lib" folder to the IDE Interpreter.

In IDE of IntelliJ like PyCharm you go to settings -> project -> project interpreter -> click on settings small button -> show all

[image]

Then click on folders icon:

[image]

Then click on add icon:

[image]

Then pick your lib folder

[image]